# no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >::push_back(int)'

Tags: c++, vector

I made a vector of vectors and i wanted to take values from the user.I simply don't know what is the problem with it

why can't i use `push_back()` here
and if you have any other method than this please tell.

```
vector<vector<int>>  v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   v.push_back(i+1);
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        v[i].push_back(j+1);
    }
}
```

doing this gives me error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >::push_back(int)'
v.push_back(i+1);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this statement v.push_back(i+1);?

Comment: The vector v doesn't contain ints, so you can not push back an int in line 4. You could for example pushback an empty vector, or your can use resize before the loop.

Comment: thanks sir,i completely understood the point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a vector of vectors of the type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

```
vector<vector<int>>  v;
```

It means that elements of the vector `v` has the type `std::vector<int>` not `int`.

So the compiler issues an error message for this statement

```
v.push_back(i+1);
```

that does not make a sense.

You could use such a call provided that the class template std::vector had an implicit constrictor from an integer expression to the type std::vector. However such a constructor is explicit

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Thus there is no implicit conversion from the parameter an expression supplied to the parameter `n` to the type `std::vector<int>`.

It seems you mean the following

```
vector<vector<int>>  v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   v.resize(i+1);
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        v[i].push_back(j+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding `v.resize(i+1)` - just `vector<vector<int>> v(n);` for crying out loud.

Answer (score 0):

It is because v is a vector containing a vector of ints. Meaning you can't push_back an integer as it wants an int vector.

```
vector<vector<int>>  v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    vector<int> v2;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        v2.push_back(j+1);
    }
    v.push_back(v2);
}
```

Now consider this code, it will work because you are creating a new vector of ints, v2. If you push v2 to v, it will work as v requires an int vector for push_back.

Answer (score 0):

People like to overcomplicate things when answering. The idea here is that you have created a vector inside a vector. So the first vector takes a vector as an input, whereas the second vector takes an "int". Therefore, you shouldn't push an integer in the **first** vector but a VECTOR of integers.